# InstallAnywhere: How to prevent reboot after silent uninstall?

Tags: windows, installanywhere

I have a Unistaller exe which was created with InstallAnywhere (not by me). After call the uninstaller in silent mode like

```
Uninstall.exe -i silent
```

the Windows machine will do a reboot. Is there a way to prevent this reboot?

Comment: Ask the person who wrote the uninstaller.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of InstallAnywhere, but this site is my go to for making silent installers do what I want.  Maybe one of the switches mentioned here will work for that as well.
http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php

or what happens if you do a uninstall.exe -? or /? or -h or -help, hopefully it's like most install platforms and then gives you a list of the options you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Install anywhere can receive variables values over commind-line after -D switch. Say if you want to pass value "NO" to a variable $RESTART_NEEDED$ run uninstaller as follows:
uninstall.exe -DRESTART_NEEDED=NO -i silent.
Check out standard IA variables:
https://docs.revenera.com/installanywhere2018/Content/helplibrary/ia_ref_variables_std_ia_vars.htm

Be aware that if installer changes this variable value according to some logic in process of uninstallation then this action will not help. Depends on installer.